# Exception on SSL certificate "Trust anchor for certification path not found"

Tags: android, okhttp, android-networking, android-security

The exception I get is:

`javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.`

I know I can get around this by having my own `X509TrustManager` but I have also heard that is not allowed on the Play Store. This is on domains that I do not control so I can't fix the server.

What are some implementations that would be allowed? would it be enough if I asked the user if they trust that?

Thanks.

Comment: Having your own trust manager is allowed I believe.  Turning off trust management is not allowed.

Comment: As long as I have some logic in the decision then it is ok?